# "До каких" в вопросе

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов, фразеология

Написал

*А до каких мероприятие продлится?*

и задумался, насколько это нормативная и литературная форма. Не нашёл ссылок ни на словари, ни других, где бы упоминалось это выражение.

Если вдруг непонятно, смысл здесь тот же, что и у "до скольких".

Answer (score 2):

Это что-то совсем далеко от нормы.
"До скольких" - уже просторечие, правда ныне всеми силами подтягивается до разговорного (обсуждаемо, см. ниже). Ну а "до каких" - это что-то очень странное. Настолько странное, что и в справочники не попало.

Добро бы еще "до каких пор". Экспрессивно и не тот смысл, но все-таки можно принять как вариант нормы. А просто "до каких..."?

А вообще-то "до которого часа" никто не отменял.

@Екатерина

> На Грамоте.ру несколько ответов такого рода: "Местоимение сколько
> склоняется в зависимости от строя предложения. Правильно: до скольких
> работает магазин (родительный падеж), со скольких работает магазин
> (родительный падеж), ко скольким (дательный падеж). Неправильное
> употребление можно объяснить неграмотностью (часто люди не знают, что
> это слово в принципе склоняется) или небрежностью говорящего".

Я видел эти справкины упражнения. Там, насколько могу судить, в основном обсуждается падежные формы (ибо "до сколька", "до скольки" и проч. слышатся постоянно).

А по нашей теме  вопрос только один. Как вы в этом контексте понимаете "до скольких"? "До скольких времен"? Не прокатит. "До скольких часов"? Но это противоречит историческому использованию "час" с порядковым числительным.
Можно сказать "Сколько времени прошло?", но не "со скольких/до скольких времен".

Отсюда и моё отношение к этой форме как к разговорно-просторечной.

//===

Насчет "до скольких". Появление формы "Сколько времени" вместо "Который час" объясняют сокращением от "Сколько времени прошло от полуночи/полудня?". Хитровато, но можно согласиться. Но "до скольких" даже в эту конструкцию не вписывается. Тут явно речь о чем-то счетном. Так что тут, если речь идет о времени, "до скольких" не намного лучше, чем "до каких", разве что более распространено.

Comment: Спасибо! Совсем, значит, ненормативно... Жалко. Звучит красиво просто.

Comment: Ну в общем-то это имхо. Подождите, может кто меня и опровергнет.

Comment: Насчёт "до скольких". На Грамоте.ру несколько ответов такого рода: "Местоимение сколько склоняется в зависимости от строя предложения. Правильно: до скольких работает магазин (родительный падеж), со скольких работает магазин (родительный падеж), ко скольким (дательный падеж).

Неправильное употребление можно объяснить неграмотностью (часто люди не знают, что это слово в принципе склоняется) или небрежностью говорящего".

Comment: @Екатерина, это "справка", не сама грамота. Авторитетность еще ниже. Остальное - ив ответ добавил.

Answer (score 0):

В словаре есть такое значение: ***До каких  пор***, в зн. нареч. **До какого времени, момента; как долго.** До каких пор я буду терпеть это безобразие?

[http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=пора&all=x](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0&all=x)

***До каких*** – это, вероятно, сокращенный (разговорно-просторечный) вариант этого выражения.

Comment: Ну, я бы не сказал, что это вариант того же выражения. *До каких пор = сколько ещё,* а *до каких = до которого часа* или *до какого времени.*

Comment: Не сказали бы? Но зачем вам что-то говорить, если в словаре ясно указано значение наречного выражения «до каких пор», то есть «до какого времени, момента; как долго». У вас то же самое значение: А до каких (до какого времени, как долго) мероприятие продлится? Только концовка в разговорном варианте усечена. Впрочем, не исключено, что мы по-разному читаем словари.

Comment: Да, как долго. "До какого времени" в том же значении "как долго", без точного упоминания времени.